# How to update a variable and how to make have the updated value after the restart of the progr?

Tags: c++, variables

I wrote an algorithm in C++, but I'd like to know how to update an int type variable, for example:

```
int a = 100;
a = a - 50;
```

So that the next time the program is started the variable is no longer 100 but 50 and so on. First of all I would like to know if it can be done.

```
int a = 100;

a = a - 50;

//now it's no longer 100 but 50; at the restart of the program it will be 100 again and I don't want that.
```

Answer (score 1):

"So that the next time the program is started " - variables exist *only* in the running programs memory. They are *not* persistent between multiple runs of an application. If you want to persist/re-use data between runs, you have to save/load the data to/from a file or other persistent storage.